# retrieve selected option from dropbox menu using flask/ajax

Tags: html, ajax, flask

I am trying to retrieve the selected option from dropdown menu. But it seems to be returning me none. I tried using ajax to post the selected value but it doesn't work as well. Please enlighten me.

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/dashboard",
    type:"POST",
    data: {
Sel =data['Sel']
},
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {}})
```

In flask where request.method="POST":

```
@app.route('/dashboard',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
select= request.form.get('val')
# select= request.form.get('Sel')
print(select)
```

In html:

```
<form action="/dashboard" method="POST" name="dashboardform" id="dashboardform">
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <p>Select Period </p>
    <select id="Sel">
      <option value="All"> All </option>
      {% for result1 in result[:] %}
      <option value="{{result1}}">{{result1}}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please post a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `None` because you are trying to receive the data as `form` data but in your, ajax request you are sending to `Flask` as JSON also the structure in the data of your ajax method needs to be fixed, to receive your JSON data in the backend you need to do it like this:

In your `ajax` method structure the `data` parameter like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"/dashboard",
    type:"POST",
    data: {'sel': data['Sel']}
},
    error: function() {
        alert("Error");
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {}
})
```

In your flask code then received with `request.json['sel']`, also you can use the method `request.get_json` to receive your JSON request data.

```
@app.route('/dashboard',methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def dashboard():
    select= request.json['sel']
    print(select)
```